# iOS, check if the app crashes because of lack of memory

Tags: ios, crash, memory-warning

How can I make sure that reason of crashes is lack of memory?
Is there anything specific in crash log?
Maybe I have to use some tools or libraries?

UPDATE: my app uses lot of memory and receives memory warnings. It's very difficult to reduce memory usage. It crashes because of memory warnings time to time. But I want to make sure that it doesn't crash because of other reasons.
So how can I check the reason of app crash (it receives lots of memory warnings every time)

UPDATE2: Application has lots of 3D graphics and complex UI that takes lots of memory for textures. Customer doesn't want to make any kind of "loading..." pauses. If I unload invisible textures in background I can't get smooth animations.

So I just need to detect **is there any crash reasons except memory**.

Comment: Maybe you can explain what's consuming the memory and we can help reducing memory usage if possible.

Comment: Added details of memory usage

Answer (score 1):

At least you could implement the method

```
- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application
```

in your app delegate, and put a log to see if this indeed you are going through it before crashing.

Comment: How can we prevent the app to crash ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apple's Instruments Tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruments_%28application%29) to profile various things such as memory usage.  This tool is bundled together with Xcode.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The answer is in the title of the link as well, in case Wikipedia happens to delete that page.  The link was more for quick access to details.  I will edit the question to be a bit more specific though.

Answer (score 0):

Product -> Profile -> leak  is a possible method to check memory leak. *Allocations* will show the total memory being used, and *leaks* will show leaks due to not releasing.

Comment: Then Tejesh Alimilli is giving a good tutorial. Check Profile -> leak -> Allocations and find out which library is using up the memory and then locate down to the specific objects.

Answer (score 0):

[how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial)

that is a useful tutorial